# Positioning content in :after pseudo-element absolutely relative to an inline elements top edge

Tags: css, layout, css-position, pseudo-element

I'm looking for a CSS-only way to position content in an `:after` pseudo element absolutely relative to another - *possibly multiline* - element's top edge. The result should resemble this:

[image: Result demonstration]

Usually there's no rocket science involved to archieve this, but I'd like to find a solution that also meets the following criteria:

- Do not use the `:before` pseudoelement (this is already needed to achieve some other independent thing),
- do not use `display: block/inline-block;` on the inline element (because it creates ugly holes in the text flow),
- allow to define the width of the elements as a percentage of the containing element (at least after applying the rule of three),
- do not hardcode the top position/margin/padding of the `:after`-pseudo-element in any way that makes it dependent of the parent element's position inside the grandparent element, the parent element's height or the actual element's height (or to make it short: don't make anything dependent of the content),
- do not insert additional HTML elements, and
- do not add JS.

I created a [Codepen](http://codepen.io/boundaryfunctions/pen/zAfrK?editors=110)  that hopefully makes it easier to grasp what I'm going for here.

I know that it is easily possible to get to the result by violating one of the restrictions listed above (as demonstrated in the Codepen), but I'm looking for an *elegant* solution to this problem where this is not needed.

After playing around with this for quite a while I'd say that it is not possible, but it would be great if someone could convince me of the contrary - or at least formally proves that it actually is impossible. Thanks a lot for any help in advance.

Comment: Is `::before` needed for something position-sensitive, too? Otherwise you can use it.

Comment: The `::after` width should be relative to `<p>` buts its `top` should relative to `<span>`, correct? I believe this is the hardest part...

Comment: Thanks for your comments. @Terry: The idea of this questions was to find a solution without using `:before` e.g. if this is already used for something else. @Luizgrs: Yes, I think this is the essence of the problem. I'm interested if there's some kind of hack or workaround to relate to both elements, one for width and the other for horizontal placement.

Comment: Why must it be a `::after` pseudo element? Can't it be a real element like http://codepen.io/HerrSerker/pen/GwJhu

Comment: @HerrSerker: Thanks for your solution. Actually I know that this is possible, but the question was more framed to question the capability of CSS than to just find a pragmatic workaround to get the job done.

Comment: @boundaryfunctions Ok, I can't see a solution 'ere with that prerequisuites.

Comment: @Herrserker Yeah, actually me neither, but I was still hoping for some quirky way to make it work while stile fulfilling all the above criteria. Thanks a lot anyway.

Comment: One question : Your demo "with relative positioning of the parent" is using hard-coded top position/margin/padding of the `:after` pseudo-element (class `.accent--relative`) so why is this part of your requirements (4th of your list)? ... would you accept an answer based on this "relative position of the parent" (`<span>`) but without using `display: inline-block;` to avoid the ugly holes in the text flow?

Comment: @JFK: Well probably I should clarify this, actually the position/margin-top/padding-top was just not meant to be defined in respect of either the parent elements height or the position of the parent inside the grandparents. So yes, a solution working around the ugly text flow hole should be ok.

Comment: The requirements you impose are impossible to meet using pure CSS

Comment: @ZachSaucier: Yes, you might be right. But the point of this question is to find out whether this really is impossible. Nobody was able to show a way to make it work *until now* but also nobody provided actual *prove* that this is impossible (which i would for sure accepts as a correct answer as well). So: let's wait if anybody ever comes up with a solution.

Comment: Take a look at this pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gLypI?editors=110 I haven't figured out why the exact same styles work in the last paragraph but won't work in the second paragraph.

Answer (score 4):

Well, the only possible solution with the wanted method could be this. 
**-** First to mention, for this to work you'd need to define `::after` `content` directly in CSS, not through `data-` attribute. (I don't know why, but seems like a parsing problem.)
**-** Set `position:relative` to the `.wrapper`. as you're going to move `::after` `left-right` based on that parent (not direct one).
**-** Set `width: 100%` to `::after` (100% of the parent)
**-** Set `white-space: pre` to `::after` - **this is important**
**-** Write the `content` directly with using `\A` (escape character) to break the word in particular places.
**-** Set `top: 0` and give it a negative `right` position (how far you want)

**Note:** You might need to set `word-wrap: break-word` on certain elemenets if the additional text is overflowing out of the wrapper.

Basically, this is the addition/modification for your CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.accent::before{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    content: "Unfortunately \A it is aligned with \A the last line of said span.";
    white-space: pre;
    right: -70%;
}

.content p {
    word-wrap: break-word; /* in my example <p> was problematic */
}
```

**Note:** I don't know how good this method is for responsive designs, never tried it that way.

Tested on FF and Chrome.
[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/x20q1kxg/5/)

**EDIT:**
Hm, yeah, I started with `::after` then by accident switched to `::before` =)

Alright, minor modifications to the CSS:

**-** Instead of `width: 100%` set `width: auto`
**-** Instead of `top: 0` you need to manually (sorry) reduce `margin-top: -(number)px` - **don't use** `top` as it's gonna set top position based on the wrapper itself.
**-** Switch `right: -(number)%` to `right: -(number)px`

CSS modification:

```
.accent::after{
    width: auto;
    right: -50px;
    margin-top: -40px;
    /* and remove "top" property completely */
}
```

[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/3hvmq13k/4/)

**ANOTHER EDIT**
Cleaner working solution where you can use `content: attr(data-meta)` (removed `white-space: pre` and set `width` to wanted percentage size:

```
.accent::after{
    position: absolute;
    width: 30%;
    content: attr(data-meta);
    right: -50px;
    margin-top: -40px;
}
```

[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/3hvmq13k/5/)

Comment: This doesn't meet the requirements because you use the `::before` pseudo-element and your solution  doesn't work any more when using `::after` instead: http://jsfiddle.net/3hvmq13k/2/. Thanks a lot for giving it a try, anyway.

Comment: Both of your newly suggested solutions break the requirements in that they hardcode the top position/margin. In both modifications this is relative to the height of `.accent` (not allowing for another number of lines inside the element, see http://jsfiddle.net/9xunLj3t/). Thanks for your effort, though.

Answer (score 0):

With these requirements I tried:

- using **bottom** [[?]](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_bottom.asp) property at the `::after` element,or
- using **translateY** [[?]](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp) property

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/w4zvmbjh/

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
         <h2>1-Unfortunately it doesn't work with multline content</h2>

        <p>Pellentesque ultrices sed quam pellentesque, eu ultricies nulla semper.
            <label for="pretty" class="accent" data-meta="Unfortunately it is aligned with the last line of said span.">Etiam leo ligula, laoreet eget urna et, dignissim facilisis nisi ante.</label>Duis gravida lectus tellus, sed rutrum nisi ultricies a. Aliquam pellentesque ante at ipsum convallis porta.</p>
         <h2>2-Unfortunately it doesn't work with multline content</h2>

        <p>Pellentesque ultrices sed quam pellentesque, eu ultricies nulla semper. <span class="accent-bottom" data-meta="Unfortunately it is aligned with the last line of said span.">Etiam leo ligula, laoreet eget urna et, dignissim facilisis nisi ante.</span> Duis gravida lectus tellus, sed rutrum nisi ultricies a. Aliquam pellentesque ante at ipsum convallis porta.</p>
    </div>
</div>

label
{
    color:red !important;
}

/* Basic typo (not problem related) */
body {
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
  font-size: 82.5%;
  line-height: 1.167;
  color: #555;
}

h1, h2 {
  color: #222;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 1.167em;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 1em;
}

/* Problem related styles */

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 580px;
  margin: 2em auto;
}

.content p {
  width: 62.069%;
}

.accent {
  color: cornflowerblue;
  &:after {
    content: attr(data-meta);
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 31.035%;
    transform:translateY(-50%)

  }
}

.accent-bottom {
  color: cornflowerblue;
  &:after {
      content: attr(data-meta);
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 31.035%;
    bottom: 14%;
  }
}
```

Comment: I think your solution only works due to the length of the text. If you add additional text to the `span data-meta` element the positioning is off.

Comment: Cannnot find other solution excerpt ::before.There is no way.